# How does python treat a for loop within a range where upper bound and lower bound is the same?

Tags: python-3.x

So if i write the following code:

```
for i in range(1,1):
<whatever>
```

does the loop exit as the i value has already exceeded the upper bound or does something else occur within the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just try it?  The lower bound of a [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) is inclusive and the upper bound is exclusive (1, 1[ so the loop body doesn't get executed:

```
list(range(1,1))
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

It exists out of the loop without executing any loop statements.